# Hodge Star operator and volume form on arbitrary manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

I guess this is the question on definitions, however, I haven't managed to find a clear answer to this question:

Suppose we have a manifold, there is metric tensor, so we can use it to calculate Hedge Star operator on differential forms.

Let $ \Omega $ be the volume form.

Is it true, that $*\Omega = 1$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to do the following math:

$\Omega \wedge *\Omega = \left(\Omega, \Omega\right)\Omega = \Omega$

$*\Omega $ is scalar, so it seems that my guess was right. Was it?

Comment: You're completely right! :)

Comment: It is important to add the assumption that the manifold is **oriented** in order to define "the" volume form $\Omega$ associated with the metric. Switching the orientation amounts to changing  $\Omega$ to $-\Omega$. Then you can just follow the definition of the Hodge operator, as you did correctly in your answer.